# almacenar tildes y ñ en mysql para app android

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es que al intentar almacenar información en mySQL las vocales con tilde y las letras ñ no se guardan correctamente. Por ejemplo, al enviar a mySQL la palabra `año` aparece `a&ntilde;o`.

He consultado ya decenas de hilos y tutoriales e intentado todo lo que he encontrado y no he conseguido solucionarlo.

Este es mi archivo PHP:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_shared_cards ( ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE, QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE, ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE, PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE, CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE, VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE, SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE )
      VALUES (:ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE, :QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE, :ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE, :PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE, :CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE, :VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE, :SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE)";



      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);


      $content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


      $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE']));


    

      $resultado->bindValue(":ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE", $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE", $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE", $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE", $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE", $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE", $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE", $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE);




      $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE'];




      $resultado->execute();



}catch(Exception $e){
      echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage()));
      exit();
}

?>
```

Actualmente la base de datos mySQL tiene cotejamiento utf8mb4_spanish_ci y lo mismo para la tabla (table_shared_cards) y la columna (QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE) que estoy probando.

Muchas gracias por adelantado, ojalá puedan ayudarme ya que he intentado todo lo que he encontrado y nada ha funcionado.

Comment: que versión de android estás utilizando?

Comment: La app la estoy probando en un móvil con Android 10

Comment: Si eso viaja en un JSON, es posible que necesites devolver el escapado que le aplicaron pa viajar. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php tal vez sirva

Comment: @Alfabravo diste con la clave. Mil gracias, me salvaste. Aplicándole "html_entity_decode" ya almacena los caracteres especiales correctamente en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la aportación de @Alfabravo solucioné el problema. Éste sería el código resultante tras aplicar el "html_entity_decode" y borrar algunas líneas que había añadido en anteriores intentos de solucionar el problema de codificación con UTF8.

```
<?php

try{

      $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database" , "root", "");
      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_shared_cards ( ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE, QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE, ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE, PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE, CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE, VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE, SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE, TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE )
      VALUES (:ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE, :QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE, :ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE, :PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE, :CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE, :VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE, :SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE, :TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE)";



      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);


      $content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


      $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE']));
      $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE=htmlentities(addslashes($content['TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE']));

      $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded = html_entity_decode($TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE);




    

      $resultado->bindValue(":ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE", $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE", $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE", $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE", $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE", $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE", $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE", $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);
      $resultado->bindValue(":TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE", $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE_decoded);




      $ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['ID_ORIGINAL_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['QUESTION_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['ANSWER_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['PACK_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['CREATOR_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['VERSION_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['SCORE_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG1_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG2_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG3_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG4_QUESTION_ONLINE'];
      $TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE = $content['TAG5_QUESTION_ONLINE'];




      $resultado->execute();



}catch(Exception $e){
      echo json_encode(array("error"=>$e->getMessage()));
      exit();
}

?>
```

Además he devuelto el cotejamiento de la base de datos, las tablas y las columnas a "utf8mb4_general_ci" ya que lo había modificado para intentar solucionar el problema.